# "Cannot add a configuration with name 'endpoints' as a configuration..."

Tags: google-app-engine, gradle, plugins

I am trying to migrate to GAE framework 2.0.  As I follow the document, I realised that when I add this line to build.gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.endpoints-framework-server'
```

I can this error message:

> Error:Cannot add a configuration with name 'endpoints' as a
>   configuration with that name already exists.

Did anyone encounter the same error?

My build.gradle is below:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
      mavenCentral()
      jcenter()
   }
   dependencies {
      classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:+'

      classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin:+'
   }
}

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
   jcenter()
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.endpoints-framework-server'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
   appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.56'

   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-testing:1.9.56'
   testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-stubs:1.9.56'

   // 2.0
   compile group: 'com.google.endpoints', name: 'endpoints-framework', version: '+'

   compile group: 'com.googlecode.junit-toolbox', name: 'junit-toolbox', version: '1.5'
   compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.50'
   compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.50'
   compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.1.5'
   compile 'org.json:json:20151123'
   compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
   compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2'
   compile 'com.ganyo:gcm-server:1.0.2'
   compile 'com.google.appengine.tools:appengine-gcs-client:0.4.4'
   //compile 'commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.3.1'
   compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:v1-rev66-1.21.0'
}

appengine {
   downloadSdk = true
   appcfg {
      oauth2 = true
   }
   endpoints {
      getClientLibsOnBuild = true
      getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
   }

   httpAddress = "0.0.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `appengine` plugin you've already applied already creates a configuration named `endpoints` - see [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/google/appengine/AppEnginePlugin.groovy#L629). Are you sure that both plugins, I mean `appengine` and `com.google.cloud.tools.endpoints-framework-server` can be used together in a project? Since there might be only one configuration with particular name.